# Which of these two ways of algorithm analysis is right? What the difference between them?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm studying about algorithm analysis and to which Assympthotic class the algorithm belongs.

I found a simple exercise in internet with two resolutions and I don't know which of them is right, or if both are right, what is the difference between them?

**RESOLUTION 1**

```
Begin
  i = 0                 // O(1)
  While i <= n do:      // O(n)
    i = i + 4           // O(1)
  print i               // O(1)
End

RESULT: This algorithm belongs to Θ = O(n).
```

**RESOLUTION 2**

```
Begin
  i = 0                 // 1
  While i <= n do:      // n
    i = i * 4           // 2n
  print i               // 1
End

RESULT: This algorithm belongs to Θ = 3n + 2.
```

A - These two resolutions are right? If yes, what is the difference between them?

B - They have to count the 'print' too?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the BigO ( O()) notation?

Comment: Yes, if a function is O it means its better or equal

Comment: That is a very ambiguous and incomplete definition. Better or equal in what sense? O() defines an upper bound on the growth rate of f(). if you say `f = O(g)` that means as the input size goes to infinity, f does not grow any faster than g. When n is something like 100 trillion, a constant like 2 is completely irrelevant, so is the coefficient 3. So `3n + 2 = O(n)`

Comment: Resolution 2 is counting operations, or maybe accesses to variable `i`. The output of resolution 2 is an estimate of **running time** for a given value of `n`. Resolution 1 is estimating the **time complexity** of the algorithm. Those two concepts, **running time** and **time complexity**, are subtly different. But running time is easily converted to time complexity. In your example, the running time `3n + 2` *is* O(n), so both methods give the same answer for the time complexity.

Comment: Resolution 2 is dead wrong. Initially `i = 0`. Then after `i = i * 4` it remains `0`. The loop never terminates; it is not `O` of anything (`O(infinity)` if you wish). OTOH if we start with `i = 1` how many times the loop body will be executed? Hint: about `log n` times.

Comment: I didnt understand your point

Comment: The point is that your edit (version 2 of the question), which changed `i = i + 4` to `i = i * 4` completely changes the run time analysis of resolution 2. And it doesn't help that you left `i = 0` as the starting value for `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious why, in Resolution 2, you marked the line `i = i + 4` as O(2n).  Does that line of code take longer to run when `n` is higher?  I don't think so - it appears that it would always take the same amount of time to run.

In general, something that is `O(1)` is something that always takes the same amount of time to run, regardless of the size of the input.  For example, a statement line `i = i + n` would take the same amount of time regardless of whether `n` was 1 or 1,000,000.

In general, something that is `O(n)` takes an amount of time that is directly proportional to `n`.  So, if `n` was twice as large, it would take twice as long to run.  Note that we are **not** saying that something that is O(n) always takes `n` steps.  It might take `2*n` steps, or `10*n` steps, or `n/2` steps, but it is always directly proportional to `n`.  For example, your while loops fit this category.  If `n` was twice as large, they would take twice as long to run.

So, there is no such thing as `O(2n)` or `O(3n)` or `O(3n+2)`.  All of those describe something that is directly proportional to `n` and so they would all be described as `O(n)`.

Of course, there are other categories, like `O(n^2)` for things that are proportional to n squared, or `O(log n)` for things that are proportional to the logarithm of n, etc.

To be clear - this explanation is intended for a beginning student who is working on developing an intuition for how to think about big-O style analysis.  A more advanced student learning about big-omega, big-theta, etc., would need much more nuanced definitions.

Comment: So, how many instructions i = i * 4 spends inside the while loop? The Print command I have to count too?